# don't show empty img src box or empty rows with no data/value

Tags: php, html, mysql

The code bellow shows data from a mysql table and it echos images paths associated with an image in an image folder but the problem arises when the data for the image path is empty their appears an empty box which I do not want. I want the empty image src box not to appear and i want that empty space to not appear as well. Basically i don't want rows of empty spaces to appear when their is no data/value in the mysql table and I do not want the image src box to appear with a blank box. The image path is called name. I used a tiny bit of javascript code below but it doesn't work.

just in case you're confused the img src button on top is linked to a light box so here is a simple img src code you can use for an example

```
    <img src="a/<?=$name ?>" />
```

Sorry everyone none of the codes below work. It all has to do with the msyql fetch and add null to the end of the msyql query. If you seen ways to do it in php it malfunctions most of the time.

HERE IS AN examaple. I hope you appreciate it.

```
   SELECT pm.mid, pm.size, pm.timestamp, pm.message, pm.name, pm.who, header.id,   header.username
     FROM pm, header
     WHERE pm.name IS NOT NULL ORDER BY pm.id2
```

Answer (score 0):

Css selectors work like this:
`img[src=""]`

Comment: i tried using CSS similar to that but all it does is hide every img src box even the ones with data. Is that how its suppose to be done, are we suppose to use Css.

Answer (score 0):

Try this around your image output code:

```
<?php                 
if( $name != '' ) {
?><a href="a/<?=$name ?>" rel='lightbox'> <img src=  "a/<?=$name ?>" width='150' height='100'   class='img' id='img'" >  </a> <?php
}
?>
```

If you want to check the file exists as well as just the database field being blank, check out [file_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)

Comment: no sadly it does not work the whole page becomes blank. Thanks anyway. I really appreciate it.

Comment: sounds like a syntax error somewhere then, I can't see why that would kill your whole page

Comment: i tried a different code but it seems it only works with firefox.

Comment: no your code is wrong and doesnt work you actually have to add null to the end of the msyql query.

Comment: work out what $name's value is when is SHOULDN'T display (by using var_dump($name) each loop), then put that specific value into your if($name != [result]), whether it be null, '', 0, unset, whatever